# Lattice of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to find the lattice of subgroups of the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_3$ and of the diedral group $\mathcal D_8$ (the group of order 8).
I searched on google, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Can't you do it for yourself? Give it a try and show your work. These are pretty small groups. The lattice for $\;S_3\;$ is pretty easy, and for $\;D_4:=\;$ the dihedral group of order $\;8\;$ is a little trickier, but not much: this group has eight proper non-trivial subgroups, if my memory doesn't fail me.

Comment: actually it's just to put a (nice) picture of them in my semester project. But I don't have problem to compute them :-)

Comment: Then google it under "lattice of dihedral group *images*" . There are several of them pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the subgroup lattice for the dihedral group of order 8 (labelled D4 in the diagram).[image: Subgroup Lattice for D4]

As Timbuc mentioned, there are lots of (nicer!) diagrams of the subgroup lattice of D4 online.

For other more obscure groups, you can use Sage (which uses GAP) to generate their subgroup lattice. I've written up a subgroup lattice generator that you can run in your browser here: http://sheaves.github.io/Subgroup-Explorer/

I've only written it for groups up to order 32, but in Sage/GAP, you should be able to generate lattices for much larger groups (might take a while though).

Comment: One might want the actual subgroups, not just their isomorphism classes.